# What knowledge is required to develop a website in php?

Tags: php

Are there any prerequisites I need to know before I build a website/web application in php?

Anything like ajax, jquery, jsp etc?

Comment: This question ultimately depends on what website you are trying to build. Why don't you just start doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PHP** is a server side technology, it means the server execute your PHP script and then send the result to the user's browser.

**JSP** is a concurrent technology based on Java. Your site will be in PHP or JSP, not both.

**AJAX** stands for "Asynchronous Javascript And XML", it is a way to obtains data from a server with reloading the whole page.

**jQuery** is a Javascript framework which greatly simplify a lot of common tasks in Javascript.

**Javascript** is a language which is usually used client side to modify the page or respond to user's action without reloading the page.

You can do a complete site using only PHP without problem. Javascript and everything related (jQuery, AJAX) will help you building a site with better user experience if you do it right.

You can add **MySQL** to the list, or any other database technology, to store data on the server.

Comment: Thanks! It was helpful to me atleast i know that what i want to learn can u tell me which tool will be greater for php.I have downloaded NetBean 6.9

Comment: Netbeans or Eclipse are good tools for web development. We're using Netbeans at work. But nearly any editor with some syntax coloring is enough.

Answer (score 0):

It completely depends on what you want to do, if you want to create a simple blog php is the only thing required, however if you would like to add more features then I would recomend starting the blog and learning more functions as you go along.

There are hundreads of tutorials out there which you can read or watch (on youtube) that will get you started. Most of the other languages such as javascript are touched on as they can make the site easier to use or just look better.

If you want to create a blog or a forum then php is all you need but you may like to start learning other languages once you have a good understanding of php. I would also recomend, if you are new to creating websites, that you should begin by creating a simple site first following a tutorial and then either adapt it or create an entirely different site after you understand the concept of php5.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, it depends on what website you're trying to build. You'll be able to get quite far with just PHP/MySQL but for advanced interactivity and dynamics I'd suggest looking into other technologies and combining these into your website along with the PHP.

However, just starting a project and then adding things as you learn is probably the best way. You'll surely get to a point where you want to add something you don't really know how to do, and a quick search will point you towards.. for example, jQuery. That's the point where you can start learning about another jQuery and try to implement whatever it was that you wanted to add to the website.

However, for basic dynamic websites, PHP will do a great job. It all depends on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to learn PHP hand in hand with MySQL, because it's a common combination for database based web applications.

For MySQL, the most important operations are [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete)

What do you want to create? Just throw in some signal words like guestbook, etc., so we can tell you more about the needed tools.

Comment: I want to develop site of blog like blogspot.com of Google but the thing is that i don't know which tool is for php. Thanks!